# Fork subdirectory of repo as a different repo in github

Tags: git, github, bower

I'd like to create a bower package / stylesheet for League of [Moveable Type's Chunk typeface](https://github.com/theleagueof/chunk) amongst other similar tasks.

I'm wondering if it's possible to fork their "webfonts" directory into a "fonts" directory in a new repo. This would allow me to create a bower.json file and stylesheet.

Thanks,

Comment: [splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think you can directly fork it on the web UI on github, but if you are ok cloning it and pushing things manually, you can do the following

- Clone the repo

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/theleagueof/chunk
  ```
- Create a branch using the git subtree command for the folder only

  ```
  git subtree split --prefix=folder_name -b new_branch
  ```
- Create a new github repo
- Add this new repo as a remote,

  ```
  git remote add upstream https://github.com/user/repo
  ```
- Push the subtree

  ```
  git push upstream new_branch
  ```

Comment: Any idea how to make the original repo recognise a "fork" created this way as a legitimate fork and allow submitting PRs ?

Comment: @vucalur hmm no, direct pull requests won't work. What you _can_ try to do is have the original repo as a remote in this new forked repo, push to the original repo, perform a subtree merge (reverse of split) on a fresh branch, and now issue a PR from this new branch.

Comment: To push the `new_branch` to the `master` branch of the new github repo, use `git push upstream new_branch:master`

Comment: the branched repo can be updated by rerunning the `subtree split` command with `--onto new_branch -b new_branch` (per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577084/forking-a-sub-directory-of-a-repository-on-github-and-making-it-part-of-my-own-r)

Comment: But this is just copying files and their history into a new repository, you loose the "fork" link on github and in the UI you cannot see changes against the fork ...

Answer (score 12):

Github has posted an article how to do this at https://help.github.com/en/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository:

> You can turn a folder within a Git repository into a brand new
>   repository.
>
> If you create a new clone of the repository, you won't lose any of
>   your Git history or changes when you split a folder into a separate
>   repository.
>
> 1. Open Terminal.
> 2. Change the current working directory to the location where you want to create your new repository.
> 3. Clone the repository that contains the subfolder.
>
>    ```
>    $ git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY-NAME
>    ```
> 4. Change the current working directory to your cloned repository.
>
>    ```
>    $ cd REPOSITORY-NAME
>    ```
> 5. To filter out the subfolder from the rest of the files in the repository, run git filter-branch, supplying this information:
>
>    - FOLDER-NAME: The folder within your project that you'd like to create a separate repository from.
>    - BRANCH-NAME: The default branch for your current project, for example, master or gh-pages.
>
>    ```
>    $ git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER-NAME  BRANCH-NAME 
>     # Filter the specified branch in your directory and remove empty commits
>     > Rewrite 48dc599c80e20527ed902928085e7861e6b3cbe6 (89/89)
>     > Ref 'refs/heads/BRANCH-NAME' was rewritten
>    ```
>
>    The repository should now only contain the files that were in your subfolder.
> 6. Create a new repository on GitHub.
> 7. At the top of your new GitHub repository's Quick Setup page, click the clipboard to copy the remote repository URL.
>
>    - Copy remote repository URL field
> 8. Check the existing remote name for your repository. For example, origin or upstream are two common choices.
>
>    ```
>    $ git remote -v
>     > origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY-NAME.git (fetch) 
>     > origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY-NAME.git (push)
>    ```
> 9. Set up a new remote URL for your new repository using the existing
>      remote name and the remote repository URL you copied in step 7.
>
>    ```
>    git remote set-url origin
>    https://github.com/USERNAME/NEW-REPOSITORY-NAME.git
>    ```
> 10. Verify that the remote URL has changed with your new repository name.
>
>     ```
>     $ git remote -v
>      # Verify new remote URL
>      > origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/NEW-REPOSITORY-NAME.git (fetch)
>      > origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/NEW-REPOSITORY-NAME.git (push)
>     ```
> 11. Push your changes to the new repository on GitHub.
>
>     ```
>     git push -u origin BRANCH-NAME
>     ```

Comment: On large repositories, this answer seems to perform orders of magnitude faster

Comment: @NoraPowers compared to what?

Comment: The new repo I created had a README, that prevented me to push, because I needed to pull, but that errored out with `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

Comment: Plus after I performed the `git filter-branch --prune-empty` the repo did not contain the subfolder only. Still all the other folders were there. So this step-by-step seems to be crappy for me.

Comment: I repeated the steps from a clean slate. I purged the previous new repository, recreated it. This time the `filter-branch --prune-empty` worked. I have no idea why it didn't work before (maybe the other repo was clean but it had extra files (excluded by gitignore BTW) when I tested stuff with an IDE. So now I had the subfolder only, and I could push into the virgin (no README, no gitignore, no LICENSE) repository.

Comment: After doing all this the GitHub UI does not recognize that this is an actual fork.