# Fork repo for a single folder

Tags: git, github, versioning, git-submodules

**Original problem:**

I am interested in forking and contributing to a public repository. Problem is, I wish to only update and retrieves updates for a single subdirectory in the public repository.

**First attempt:**

1. Fork the public repository
2. Clone the newly forked repository
3. Update .gitignore files for the unwanted folders and files
4. Untrack and delete unwanted directories and files using git "*git rm -r --cache .*"

**Problem:** When I wish to retrieve updates from the original public repository, the folders and files I have removed from my local repository are still being tracked in the public repository and thus i have to manually weed out all the unwanted content killing my process.

**I thought of doing [(described here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository):**

1. Clone public repository
2. Create another public repository
3. Use *git subtree split* to push folder to newly created public repository

**Problem:** The newly created public repository is no longer a "Fork" of the original repository and lose all the benefits such as visibility from the original repository and the creation of pull requests.

Comment: If still interested, I think the following post would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577084/forking-a-sub-directory-of-a-repository-on-github-and-making-it-part-of-my-own-r

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At git level, you have to work on the whole repository, you cannot just drop everything you don't want to work on.

You just have to do your non-git-relatied work in the folder you want, then publish your modification at the repository level.

Comment: That is unfortunate. I am going to leave this question open for a few more days. If no more suitable answer will arrive, I'll mark this as the correct answer.