# Forking sub directories out of several others and making it part of my own

Tags: git, github, repo

This is a follow up question on 
"[Forking a sub directory of a repository on GitHub and making it part of my own repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577084/)". What I want is to make a collection of sub directories from a few *different* upstreams.

I see the fist command is `git clone` in the answer above, which makes forking from several different upstreams difficult.

So, is it possible? You can answer hypothetically, or use the following concrete examples:

Collect in to my repo under the `MyPythonCol` folder, of

- The `lessons` sub directory from https://bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/src
- The `docs` sub directory from https://bitbucket.org/jblawatt/python-simple-di/src

Basically I just want to **track** the remote repo, with no intention to patch upstream.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [repo - The Multiple Git Repository Tool](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/), you can added a `Element linkfile` in your manifest file to create symbol link for those sub directories you want to use. please read [manifest-format.txt](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt) for more details.

Comment: Thanks but this is a follow up question on "Forking a sub directory of a repository on GitHub and making it part of my own repo" utilizing the `git subtree` command, and I prefer to do it manually, not using some 3rd party tools.