# Git split and purge

Tags: git, split, repository, purge

I know this is unusual, but one of my git repo, which acts as a collect-all repo, is getting too big and I'd like to split it up in two, into `repoA` and `repoB`.

I've found one way to do the splitting in "[Forking a sub directory of a repository on GitHub and making it part of my own repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577084/)", however, that only tells about splitting, I want the history to be split as well, so `repoA` will only contain history of `repoA` and not `repoB`, and vice versa. Otherwise, I'll get two repos but double the size because of all the history it is keeping.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @ElpieKay pointing out to look at `git filter-branch` (instead of the `git clean` that I found when searching with "git purge"), I found this:

https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

which is exactly what I was looking for. However, there is one more question -- how to remove `repoA` content from `repoB`? I.e., when splitting out `repoA`, I only need to do,

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter sub1/sub2/sub3 master
```

So in `repoB`, how to ***remove*** `sub1/sub2/sub3` while keep *everything else*?

Moreover, this command in above doc,

```
 git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/NEW-REPOSITORY-NAME.git
```

When I tried it, it only updated the `fetch` url, and the `push` one is still pointing to the old one. What I'm missing?

Comment: `git filter-branch` twice. One to remove repoA from the history and the other to remove repoB. Two rewritten histories will be created.

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay, OP question narrowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So in `repoB`, how to remove `sub1/sub2/sub3` while keep everything else?

You do an index-filter:

```
cd repoB
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter \
  'git rm -r -f -q --ignore-unmatch --cached sub1/sub2/sub3' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

That will remove `sub1/sub2/sub3` from `repoA`.

You will need a `git push --force` to update your upstream repo (and remove those folders from `repoA`)

Comment: Thanks @Von. I tried that, then use `git log --stat` to double check. However, there are still log entries in it that relate to the changes to `sub1/sub2/sub3`, though no associated files are listed in the log output. Are there more options we can add to completely remove all git logs that associated with `sub1/sub2/sub3`? Thx.

Comment: @xpt you can try the same command, but with `--prune-empty`, that is `git filter-branch --prune-empty ...`

Comment: Yes! `--prune-empty` does the trick! Please update the answer, and I'll accept it next.

Comment: @xpt I agree. I have included that command in the answer for more visibility.