# Keeping track of upstream changes of a specific file/folder

Tags: git

Let's say I *copied* (not forked) only one file/folder from other git directory and included it as a part into my existing project. I do not intend to change it. Is there any way of merging with upstream changes other than replacing it with a newer copy?

The situation is somewhat similar to "[Forking a sub directory of a repository on GitHub and making it part of my own repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577084/forking-a-sub-directory-of-a-repository-on-github-and-making-it-part-of-my-own-r)" but I already put the file into another git repository.

I am unsure if using sparse checkout would help ([How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)) here, since it is probably not a good idea to have a git repository inside of another git repository(?)