# How to create a Bot using bot template

Tags: botframework

I am looking how to build a bot using the option "Enterprise Bot Template" from Visual Studio, does anybody knows a tutorial or a videotutorial where can explain that step by step, cause all videos I have found talk about making  a bot using Bot Framework, but for my company reason I cant use this way to build the bot.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the latest Enterprise Bot template from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.botbuilderv4enterprise).

Be aware that the Entperise Bot is being replaced by the very new [Virtual Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-virtual-assistant-introduction?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) (which also has a template [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.VirtualAssistantTemplate)). The repo is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/). It looks like all of the Enterprise Bot documentation has been taken down and replaced by Virtual Assistant documentation.

Microsoft has a [getting started guide](https://github.com/microsoft/AI/blob/master/docs/tutorials/csharp/virtualassistant.md) for the Virtual Assistant. That being said, I'm running into a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047387/deploying-and-running-bot-framework-v4-4-from-template-works-but-deploying-and) [issues](https://github.com/microsoft/AI/issues/1326) myself while trying to get started.